# Aplicar o efeito Blur no fundo de box flutuante

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho uma função simples em jscript que abre um box flutuante, só que quando o box flutuante abre eu queria que o fundo ficasse com o efeito blur, só que eu não consigo deixa o fundo com esse efeito, já tentei diversos métodos do Google e não tive sucesso.

Já tentei de tudo, a unica coisa que eu consegui foi deixa o fundo com a cor escura, mas o efeito 'filter: blur(2px);' parece não funcionar.

```css
body > #widgetNotify {
    filter: blur(0px);
}
body > * {
    transition: filter 0.2s linear;
}

#widgetNotify {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 999999999;
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: #00000094;
}

#widgetNotify::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    font: inherit
}

#widgetNotify * {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

#widgetNotify .widget {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    font-family: "UOLText", "UOLTextRegular", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: none;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

#widgetNotify .widget * {
    outline: 0
}

#widgetNotify .widget .messagesContainer {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 1px rgba(76, 76, 76, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 1px rgba(76, 76, 76, 0.3);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 1px rgba(76, 76, 76, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 1px rgba(76, 76, 76, 0.3);
    margin-top: 7px;
    z-index: 6000001;
    line-height: 1.2
}

#widgetNotify .widget.opened .messagesContainer {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible
}

#widgetNotify .widget .messagesContainer.loginbox {
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0
}

#widgetNotify .widget.widget-template-desktop .messagesContainer.loginbox {
    top: 100% !important;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 405px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}

#widgetNotify .widget.widget-template-desktop .messagesContainer.loginbox {
    height: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #e6e6e6;
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 50% !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    margin-left: -305px !important;
    margin-top: -222.5px !important;
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#widgetNotify .widget.widget-template-desktop .messagesContainer.loginbox::after {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: .8;
    z-index: -1;
}

#widgetNotify .widget.widget-template-desktop .messagesContainer {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 7px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="widgetNotify" class="widgetNotify" style="display: block;">
   <div class="widget widget-template-desktop opened widget-align-right">
       <div class="messagesContainer loginbox modal-login manual-modal-login"></div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: você terá de fazer uma chamada via javascript para quando chamar a caixa deixar os outros elementos com o seguinte efeito do css: .blur{ -webkit-filter: blur(5px); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */ filter: blur(5px); }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara fiz uma adaptação [desse código](https://codepen.io/lachama/pen/JWarNV) e usei o Bootstrap apenas para aproveitar o script do Modal. Mas a ideia vc pode adaptar facilmente ao seu projeto caso use jQuery!

A ideia aqui é quando o modal estiver aberto, vc coloca uma classe no `container` e tudo que estiver dentro fica com `filter:blur` menos o elemento que tem a classe `.modal`

Veja como fica no exemplo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<style>
.firstBlur {
  margin:20px 20px 0;
  padding:20px;
  position:relative;
}
/* coloque blur em todos os elementos menos no elemento com a class .modal */
.firstBlur.modalBlur > *:not(.modal) {
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  filter: blur(8px);
}
/* remove a cor escurecida do fundo, se quiser que fique escurecido ajuste a opacidade para 0.5*/
.modal-backdrop.show {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="firstBlur">
        <h2>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
        <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
            industry's standard
        </p>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">
            Abrir modal
        </button>

        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle"
            aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="true" data-keyboard="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">Modal Body</div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        (function () {
            //Show Modal
            $('#exampleModalLong').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
                $('.firstBlur').addClass('modalBlur');
            })
            //Remove modal
            $('#exampleModalLong').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
                $('.firstBlur').removeClass('modalBlur');
            })
        })();
    </script>
    
</body>

</html>
```

---

**OBS:** Essa resposta pode te interessar, nela eu fiz o efeito de forma inversa, começa com tudo embaçado com `filter:blur`, depois ao clicar em um `.btn` o `blur` é removido do fundo e as coisas ficam nítidas.

Comment: obrigado, erra isso que eu estava procurando, vou adaptar no meu template.

Comment: @VitorHugo legal que resolveu, o macete eh colocar a classe no pai e quando o pai tiver essa classe todos os filhos ficam com Blur, o principal aqui eh mais o CSS do que o script rss, então tenha atenção na hora de organizar o CSS, boa sorte ai tmj

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite!

Não compreendi bem sua pergunta, mas pelo que analise, você está aplicando o filtro blur na div que está acima do conteúdo, e desfocando todo conteúdo, por isso não está dando certo. Acredito que separando o fundo que receberá o filtro, do container da mensagem será melhor.

Por exemplo:

```css
#widgetNotify::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    font: inherit
}

#widgetNotify * {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

#widgetNotify .widget {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    font-family: "UOLText", "UOLTextRegular", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: none;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

#widgetNotify .widget * {
    outline: 0
}

#widgetNotify .widget .messagesContainer {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 1px rgba(76, 76, 76, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 1px rgba(76, 76, 76, 0.3);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 1px rgba(76, 76, 76, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px 1px rgba(76, 76, 76, 0.3);
    margin-top: 7px;
    z-index: 6000001;
    line-height: 1.2
}

#widgetNotify .widget.opened .messagesContainer {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible
}

#widgetNotify .widget .messagesContainer.loginbox {
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 0
}

#widgetNotify .widget.widget-template-desktop .messagesContainer.loginbox {
    top: 100% !important;
    position: absolute;
    max-height: 405px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    min-width: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}

#widgetNotify .widget.widget-template-desktop .messagesContainer.loginbox {
    height: 100%;
    border: solid 1px #e6e6e6;
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 50% !important;
    left: 50% !important;
    margin-left: -305px !important;
    margin-top: -222.5px !important;
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#widgetNotify .widget.widget-template-desktop .messagesContainer.loginbox::after {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: .8;
    z-index: -1;
}

#widgetNotify .widget.widget-template-desktop .messagesContainer {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin-top: 7px
}

.box-background-blur {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    filter: blur(5px);
    z-index: 999;
    background: #00000094;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Trabalho do Forum</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="widgetNotify" class="widgetNotify" style="display: block;">
        <div class="widget widget-template-desktop opened widget-align-right">
            <div class="messagesContainer loginbox modal-login manual-modal-login">
                <p>
                    Exemplo
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-background-blur"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: boa noite, e obrigado pela resposta, eu tentei isso, acontece que o conteúdo que fica atrás do box não fica desfocado, eu estou querendo algo assim - https://prnt.sc/ldtw5u